# Linq check value in SQL table always is false

Tags: c#, linq

I tried to check if the cost or benefit value exists for the selected Id, then I will get the cost or benefit value from the table.
In the code below my if statement doesn't work and seems to always be false but the return benefit value works fine. Where is the problem?

```
    public string GetCostBenefitAmount(int id)
    {
        if (db.CostBenefits.Any(c => c.ID == id && !c.Cost.Equals(0)))
        {
            return db.CostBenefits.Select(c => c.Cost).First().ToString();
        }
        return db.CostBenefits.Where(c=> c.ID == id).Select(c => c.Benefit).First().ToString();
    }
```

This is my code in windows form for fill txtAmount textBox by GetCostBenefitAmount(int id) method:

```
            var stockIdList = db.CostBenefitRepository.GetAllID();                
            int id = stockIdList[listBox.SelectedIndex];
            CostBenefit costBenefit = db.GenericCostBenefitRepository.GetById(id);
            txtStockName.Text = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            txtSoldAmount.Text = costBenefit.SoldAmount.ToString();
            ComboCostBenefit.SelectedItem = db.CostBenefitRepository.GetCostBenefitOperation(id);
            txtAmount.Text = db.CostBenefitRepository.GetCostBenefitAmount(id);
```

Comment: Needs more details. What is `db`? Or: is this Entity Framework, and which version? What does the `CostBenefit` class look like?

Comment: db is UnitOfWork Class that access to Entity Framework v6. and CostBenefit is a model from Sql table.

Comment: In my CostBenefit table i have (ID, Cost(Bigint), Benefit(Bigint)).
then in windows form i tried fill cost or benefit amount textBox during form load. all things are ok except txtSoldAmount.Text.

Comment: I added my windows form code in firs post.

Comment: Well, one error is that you don't filter on `ID` in `return db.CostBenefits.Select(...`.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold,

it work fine now.

Comment: @GertArnold I was just updating my answer to suggest his issue was in `return db.CostBenefits.Select(c => c.Cost).First().ToString();` statement. Oh well...  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks  @YosefBernal for your help too.

Answer (score 3):

The `Object.Equals` method determines whether two object instances are equal. Try `if (db.CostBenefits.Any(c => c.ID == id && c.Cost != 0))`. For more info on the `Object.Equals` function see [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netcore-3.1).

**Edit:**
As @Gert Arnold commented, the issue was in the `return db.CostBenefits.Select(c => c.Cost).First().ToString();` where there was no filtering done before returning.

Comment: What you say isn't true at two levels. If this was LINQ to objects, int.Equals would return true, because it compares value objects. But since this (very likely) is LINQ to a SQL backend, the entire statement is translated into SQL, which will result in a regular `=` comparison.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for the clarification, will update soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think equals is only when you are using in a join. So just use

```
c.Cost != 0
```

instead.

Comment: Odd. I'd say check your data and try it in SQL first and then Linq but that should have worked. I'm stumped.

Comment: I tried it first in SQL and work fine.

select * from CostBenefit where ID = 5 and Cost != 0

but don't work with linq.

Comment: You than need to add the    ` Where(c => c.ID == id)` as you were just taking the first item in the table.